# Python & biology: using python to intersect datasets

Tags: python, list

Love the website. I am a biologist that takes simple questions and makes them convoluted in python, currently stuck on a rather simple problem. I have two unequal lists of tuples that contain chromosome ('chr#') and position ('start', 'end') information:

list1: length=1499, tuples=('chr5', '12345', '12678')

list2: length=75220, tuples=('chr5', '44', '7777777')

If someone could explain to me why this code fails, I may figure this out on my own:

```
list1 = [('chr1', '123', '345'), ('chr1', '567', '678'), ('chr2', '123', 234'),...)

list2 = [('chr1', '123', '567'), ('chr1', '777', '890'), ('chr2', '1', 288'),...)
newlist = []

for j,k,l in list1:
      if j == x for x,y,z in list2:
            if int(k) >= int(y) or int(l) <= int(z):
                 newlist.append(k)
            else:
                 pass
      else:
            pass
```

Reasoning: I wish to compare the integers in all tuples from both strings but only when item[0] of both tuples matche.
I would greatly appreciate any help and tips, thank you!

Comment: It's true, you take simple questions and make them convoluted. This one is so convoluted that you seem the only one able to answer.

Comment: Allow me to edit into a simpler form, sorry!

Comment: I hope that makes it better!

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel (and Python is the wrong tool for this, anyway). If you're trying to find overlaps between genomic ranges, use a dedicated tool like BEDOPS, which is written to be efficient at this and similar set operations: http://bedops.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: For instance, to determine if elements `chr5 12345 12678`, `chr5 44 7777777`, etc. overlap, you can put them into a tab-delimited BED file, sort them with `sort-bed`, and then run `bedmap --echo --count foo.bed` to count the number of overlaps. If an element's count is greater than zero, then it has an overlap. You can add the `--echo-map` option to list the overlapping elements.

Comment: Thank you for the response Alex! I will definitely check this tool out: I figured someone smarter than be **must** have coded something similar already, the problem is finding it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change the first if statement in your code so it isn't before the second for loop the code runs:

```
list1 = [('chr1', '123', '345'), ('chr1', '567', '678'), ('chr2', '123', '234')]

list2 = [('chr1', '123', '567'), ('chr1', '777', '890'), ('chr2', '1', '288')]
newlist = []

for j,k,l in list1:
    for x,y,z in list2:
        if j == x:
            if int(k) >= int(y) or int(l) <= int(z):
                newlist.append(k)
            else:
                 pass
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if list1[0] == list2[0]:
  print
```

Is this what you were looking for ? :)

If you need to compare numbers as well:

```
if list1[0] == list2[0]:
    for i in range(1, min([len(list1), len(list2)]):
        if int(list1[i]) < int(list2[i]):
            print('Aha!')
```

Comment: The number comparison code may indeed be what I am looking for. I edited the question so that other humans can understand it

Answer (score 0):

My post does not answer your question, but I think your code can be improved by using more pythonic constructs. A first step toward this direction would be to use *named tuples* so that the chromosomes fields can be accessed by their attributes *name*, *start* and *end*:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Chromosome = namedtuple('Chromosome', ['name', 'start', 'end'])
chromo = Chromosome('chr1', 123, 345)
# You can access the fields as chromo.name, chromo.start and chromo.end
```

In a second step you can use list comprehensions to reduce the number of nested loops:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Chromosome = namedtuple('Chromosome', ['name', 'start', 'end'])

list1 = [Chromosome('chr1', 123, 345), Chromosome('chr1', 567, 678), ]
list2 = [Chromosome('chr1', 123, 567), Chromosome('chr2', 1, 288), ]

newlist = []
for chromo1 in list1:
    # Build a list of chromosomes from list2 that
    #  * have the same name as chromo1
    #  * start before chromo1
    #  * end after chromo1
    matches = [chromo2 for chromo2 in list2
               if chromo2.name == chromo1.name and
               (chromo2.start < chromo1.start or chromo2.end > chromo1.end)]
    newlist.extend(matches)
```

Comment: Interesting, I will play around with namedTuple. Thank you very much for the response it is greatly appreciated!